# Performance problems with joined tables

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am using Grails 1.3.7 with hibernate 1.3.7 with MySQL 5.1. I have the following (simplified) domain object:

```
class Document {
    String externalId
    Date date
    String url
    String title

    Map metadata = new HashMap()

    def propertyMissing(String key) { return   metadata[key] }
    def propertyMissing(String key, String value) { metadata[key] = value } 
}
```

When I have to load a bunch of these documents to return to the client, the system winds up having to run a separate query for each document to get the associated metadata. This takes tens of seconds on a reasonable machine to retrieve a few hundred documents with their metadata. Needless to say, this is too slow for interactive use. As my application wants to load all the data into the browser to let the user manipulate it, I cannot divide the query into "pages."

Currently, the query I am running looks like this:

```
Document.executeQuery("select distinct p.document from Posting p where p.topic = :topic", [topic: topic]);
```

This query then causes a bunch of `Document` instances to be created, which is what takes a long time.

Hibernate caching is configured as follows:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

The tables in question are:

```
mysql> describe document;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version     | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| external_id | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title       | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe document_metadata;
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| metadata     | bigint(20)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| metadata_idx | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| metadata_elt | varchar(4096) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Short of dumping the metadata table and hard-coding fields in the `Document` directly, is there something else I can do to improve the performance of my code?

Gene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can optimize the data retrieve operation with native sql calls

```
def sql = '''
  select distinct d.*, m.* 
  from 
    document d 
      join document_metadata m on m.metadata = d.id
      join post p on p.id = d.post_id
  where
    post.topic = :topic'''

def query = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
query.addEntity(com.yourdomain.Document.class)
query.setString("topic", "grails")
def documents = query.list()
```

Obviously the select is incomplete because I'm guessing post scheme and relationships

Comment: By the way, check indexes in databases.

Comment: aha! I added an index to the document_metadata table, and that improved things considerably!

Comment: Cool. I recommend you to check your database connections and queries with p6spy. You will see that hibernate generate a bunch of queries that can be replaced if you try the above solution with native sql calls

Comment: Thanks! I do see a bunch of SQL in the logs when I enable `DEBUG 'org.hibernate.SQL'` tracing. With the index per your above suggestion, the time went down to 1-2 seconds, which is OK, if not great. Now the dominating factor is the JSON serialization, which takes 6-8 seconds.

Comment: I am a bit reluctant to introduce SQL into the code as I would like to keep it database-agnostic...

Comment: I understand, but you can to use standard old vanilla plain sql with moderation. Now, you can improve your JSON serialization taking data directly from sql input. I know, it is raw but is blasting fast.

Comment: As it turns out, the first join is not necessary, and in fact, introduces duplicate records in the documents list. But the overall approach works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the metadata in an association Domain class and rely on Grails' default lazy-loading of associations.  Then you can load the core information for each `Document` faster and only load the metadata on access of a specific `Document`.

```
class Document {
    // Core non-Map data

    DocumentMetadata metadata

    def propertyMissing(String key) { return metadata?.data?.get(key) }
    def propertyMissing(String key, String value) { 
        if (!metadata) { metadata = new DocumentMetadata() }
        metadata.data[key] = value
    }
}

class DocumentMetadata {
    Map data = new HashMap()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I need these documents, I need them all, as they are being sent to the client. So deferring metadata loading won't help there.